# npm cannot start on server

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm

I have created my first Angular2 application and I want to deploy it on a server. On my development platform the application runs fine (Pycharm on Windows) and when I run the application on the server I get the following error. I have no idea what is wrong? The code can be found on https://github.com/DamenShipyards/DatabaseChecksFrontend

```
C:\DatabaseChecksFrontend>npm start

> DatabaseChecksFrontend@1.0.0 start C:\DatabaseChecksFrontend
> tsc && concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite"

app/app.module.ts(8,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module './check.component'.
app/app.module.ts(9,31): error TS2307: Cannot find module './groups.component'.
app/app.module.ts(10,29): error TS2307: Cannot find module './grid.component'.
app/app.module.ts(11,38): error TS2307: Cannot find module './highlightcode.dire
ctive'.

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.9.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! DatabaseChecksFrontend@1.0.0 start: `tsc && concurrently "npm run tsc:w
" "npm run lite" `
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the DatabaseChecksFrontend@1.0.0 start script 'tsc && concurr
ently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite" '.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the DatabaseChecksFronten
d package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     tsc && concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite"
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs DatabaseChecksFrontend
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls DatabaseChecksFrontend
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\DatabaseChecksFrontend\npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's because you run npm without `sudo` privileges. You can read more about this issue at the following official docs from npm : [npm permission issue](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions)

Comment: `sudo` is the best

Answer (score 0):

There are no files named `./check.component.ts`, `./groups.component.ts`, `./grid.component.ts` and `./highlightcode.directive.ts` in your app folder. You can only import something from modules that actually exists.

Maybe it works on your development because you have a dirty folder. Clone this same repository somewhere else and try to run it again, it should fail.